# class-validator: validate number of digits for numeric values

Tags: javascript, typescript, class-validator

I'm trying to validate the number of digits for numeric values using `class-validator`. For example: my entity can accept only numbers of 6 digits for a given property. This way

```
const user1 = new User();
user1.code = 123456 // should be valid

const user2 = new User();
user2.code = 12345 // should be invalid

const user3 = new User();
user2.code = 1234567 // should be invalid
```

I've tried using a combination of IsNumber, MinLength and MaxLength; but not worked.

```
class User {
    @IsPositive()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    @IsNumber({ maxDecimalPlaces: 0 })
    @MinLength(6)
    @MaxLength(6)
    public code: number;
}
```

I'm receiving a message saying that `code must be shorter than or equal to 6 characters`.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

MinLength and MaxLength are used to check the length of a string whereas the property you are using is a number.
I would suggest using Min and Max instead to check if it is a six digit number. ( @Min(100000) and @Max(999999) should do it )

Answer (score 1):

Just chiming in to say you can also accomplish this with a regular expression `@Matches(/^\d{6}$/)`.